# Laravel: NotReadableException in AbstractDecoder.php line 339. Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating an avatar upload system for my project. I just can't seem to get around this error....

Here is the code

```
    public function update_avatar(Request $request){
    // Handle the user upload of avatar
    if($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filelocation = public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename );

        Image::make($avatar->getRealPath())->resize(300, 300)->save($filelocation);

        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->avatar = $filename;
        $user->save();
    }

    return view('user.profile', array('user' => Auth::user()) );

}
```

Here is the error

```
    in AbstractDecoder.php line 339
at AbstractDecoder->init(false) in AbstractDriver.php line 64
at AbstractDriver->init(false) in ImageManager.php line 50
at ImageManager->make(false) in Facade.php line 221
at Facade::__callStatic('make', array(false)) in ProfileController.php line 26
at Image::make(false) in ProfileController.php line 26
at ProfileController->update_avatar(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ProfileController), 'update_avatar'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 55
at Controller->callAction('update_avatar', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(ProfileController), 'update_avatar') in Route.php line 204
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 160
at Route->run() in Router.php line 559
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
```

thats some of the error anyway...

Thanks guys

Comment: Does `$avatar->getRealPath()` return also the name of image? Not only path? Because first paramter in `Image::make` have to be complete path to image (with image name and extension too)

Comment: Honestly I'm not too sure. At a guess no it doesn't. If I remove getRealPath() I get this error ----  NotReadableException in Decoder.php line 20: Unable to read image from file ().

Answer (score 0):

According to the error log, method `getRealPath()`is returning `false`. You may want to check if the file is valid before doing anything. You can do that via the `isValid()` method.

Also your code seems to be overcomplicated to store a uploaded photo. A method exists to do so, you may want to use this one : `storeAs('images', 'filename.jpg'`

Comment: Will the storeAs work with a differetn users uploading their own photo/updating it. I was following the devdojos way of uploading a user image